# Update with Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SourceTable
-----------
Global_id int
Product_id varchar
Category int
Status int


Client
------
Client_id
Global_id
...


References
----------
Client_id
Category int
Status int
...
```

I am trying to update values of `Category` and `Status` columns in `References` table. The source data with which to update comes from the following query (returns more than one row).

```
select * from SourceTable where Product_id = 'id01234';
```

Then by `Global_id`s in the result from the above query I can update the `References` table. However, the `Global_id` column is not on the `References` table, but on the `Client` table.

How can I construct an `update` statement to update the `References` table? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Status = T3.Status , T2.Category = T3.Category
FROM References AS T1 INNER JOIN Clients AS T2 on T1.Client_Id = T2.CLient_Id 
INNER JOIN (select * from SourceTable where Product_id = 'id01234') AS T3 ON T2.Global_id = T3.Global_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following.  However if one `Product_id` may return multiple rows for single `Global_id`, it means one `Global_id` can match multiple Categories and status.  That will cause problems.

```
UPDATE r SET r.Category=t.Category,r.Status=t.Status 
FROM #References AS r
INNER JOIN #Client AS c ON r.Client_id=c.Client_id
INNER JOIN #SourceTable AS t ON t.Global_id=t.Global_id
WHERE t.Product_id='id01234'
```

Here's a full example script:

```
CREATE TABLE #SourceTable(Global_id int,Product_id VARCHAR(100),Category int,Status INT)
INSERT INTO #SourceTable 
SELECT 1,'id01234',10,1 union
SELECT 1,'id01235',11,0

CREATE TABLE #Client(Client_id int,Global_id INT)
INSERT INTO #Client
SELECT 100,1 UNION SELECT 200,1

CREATE TABLE #References(Client_id INT,Category INT,Status INT)
INSERT INTO #References(Client_id)
SELECT 100 UNION SELECT 200

UPDATE r SET r.Category=t.Category,r.Status=t.Status 
FROM #References AS r
INNER JOIN #Client AS c ON r.Client_id=c.Client_id
INNER JOIN #SourceTable AS t ON t.Global_id=t.Global_id
WHERE t.Product_id='id01234'

SELECT * FROM #References
```

```
Client_id   Category    Status
----------- ----------- -----------
100         10          1
200         10          1
```